# Error con arreglo en clase abstracta (Cliente is abstract; cannot be instantiated )

Tags: java, array, clase-abstracta

Tengo una clase abstracta llamada Cliente con dos subclases. En el archivo del main (llamado PruebaCliente) necesito hacer un array pero al momento de tratar de iniciarlo me da el mensaje "Cliente is abstract; cannot be instantiated".

```
    // Arreglo de clientes
        Cliente[] arreglo = new Cliente[10];
// Inicializa cada elemento del arreglo de clientes con un objeto de la clase Cliente
        int j = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            arreglo[i] = new Cliente("Cliente" + (i + 1),i);
        }
```

Me marca ese error en la linea:

> arreglo[i] = new Cliente("Cliente" + (i + 1),i);

¿alguien sabrá decirme por qué?

Answer (score 1):

Si has declarado Cliente como una clase abstracta no se puede instanciar, como bien te indica el error.

Si conoces algo acerca de las clases abstractas (que espero que si porque la estás utilizando), sabrás que en ellas no puedes, por ejemplo, implementar métodos abstractos, si que puedes implementar métodos pero no abstractos.

Para trabajar con una clase abstracta, lo que tienes que hacer es crear otra clase que herede de ella, donde sobreescribirás los métodos declarados como abstractos en la clase Cliente(si tienes métodos abstractos en Cliente, sino no).

Una vez que crees una clase que herede de Cliente, ya podrás trabajar con dicha clase: crear objetos, utilizar sus métodos...

Mira este documento donde explica bien lo que son las clases abstractas y como utilizarlas.https://www.aprenderaprogramar.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=668:clases-y-metodos-abstractos-en-java-abstract-class-clases-del-api-ejemplos-codigo-y-ejercicios-cu00695b&catid=68&Itemid=188

Comment: Sí se pueden implementar métodos en las clases abstractas, lo que no se puede es instanciar objetos de una clase abstracta, pero no es necesario que todos (o ni siquiera uno) de los métodos sean también abstractos

Comment: Disculpa, no se implementan los métodos abstractos, puede tener métodos no abstractos

Comment: Correcto, pero tu segundo párrafo da a entender que *todos* los métodos tienen que abstractos

Comment: ya lo he editado